# Filter from a dataframe and create another dataframe using r

Tags: r

I have two data frames as following:

```
df <- data.frame(month = c("mazda", "yamaha"),
                 april = c(11,12),
                 may = c(14,15)) 

df_whole <- data.frame(month = c("car", "bikes"),
                 april = c(.1,.2),
                 may = c(.5,.2))
```

What I want to do is create a row called `total_car` which would be a product of `car` and `mazda`. However if `df_whole` doesnt have  row `car` I would still like to create a row `total_car` which would `mazda*0`.The output I want to get to is as below. How could I calculate something like this in R

```
df_car <- data.frame(month = c("mazda", "yamaha","total"),
                 april = c(11,12,1.1),
                 may = c(14,15,7))
```

Comment: How do I know that `mazda` is multiplied by `car` and not by `bikes`? What happens to the `bikes` row of `df_whole`? What do you mean by *"if `df_whole` doesnt have row `car`"*? What's the general format of `df_whole`?

Comment: I want to show three tables one is `df` ,second being `df_whole` and third being `df_car` .The dataframe`df_whole` is being derived from some other table which always might not have the row `car`. So if `car` doesnt exist I would still like to create df_whole and multiply `mazda` with `0` . I would like filter  `df_whole %>% filter(df_whole$month =="car")`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a sql query would work better to join your tables and get the summary data.

Here's a `tidyverse` solution (note the `inner_join()`, which is sql):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data_frame(month = c("mazda", "yamaha"),
                 april = c(11,12),
                 may = c(14,15)) 

df_whole <- data_frame(month = c("car", "bikes"),
                       april = c(.1,.2),
                       may = c(.5,.2)) 

# adds car row if missing  - there is probably a better way to handle the missing data
if (!"car" %in% df_whole$month) df_whole <- bind_rows(df_whole, data_frame(month = "car"))

# converts NAs to 0
df_whole[is.na(df_whole)] <- 0

# convert to long format
df_long <- df %>%
  rename("brand" = "month") %>%
  gather(key = "month", value = "val", april:may)

df_whole_long <- df_whole %>%
  rename("type" = "month") %>%
  gather(key = "month", value = "val", april:may)

# calcualte the multiplication
dat <- inner_join(df_long, df_whole_long, by = "month") %>% # combine dfs
  filter(brand == "mazda", type == "car") %>% # filter out key rows
  mutate(total = val.x * val.y) # do multiplication and add into new column

# reformat and append
df_car <- bind_rows(df,
          bind_cols(data_frame(month = "total"),
                    dat %>%
                      select(month, total) %>%
                      spread(month, total)))
```

df_car is:

```
   month april may
1  mazda  11.0  14
2 yamaha  12.0  15
3  total   1.1   7
```

I used `tidyverse` data frames (`data_frame()` rather than `data.frame()`) so strings weren't converted to factors (the same can be achieved by adding `stringsAsFactors = F` to `data.frame()`) and I converted your data to long format, which would probably be a better structure for your database anyway.