# Multiply two rows from same dataframe r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where I want to calculate a new row based on the two existing rows by multiplying them. The structure of my dataframe is as below:

```
structure(list(month = c("mazda", "yamaha", "car"), april = c(11, 
12, 0.1), may = c(14, 15, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "month", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    2L, 0L, 1L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    month = c("car", "mazda", "yamaha")), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame", vars = "month", drop = TRUE))
```

I want to add a row `total` which would be a product of `mazda` and `car`. And if row car is not found it should be   `0` in the new row `total`.
Desired output I am trying to achieve :

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   month [4]
  month  april   may
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 mazda   11    14  
2 yamaha  12    15  
3 car      0.1   0.5
4 total    1.1   7
```

Comment: Isn't this in essence a duplicate of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375719/filter-from-a-dataframe-and-create-another-dataframe-using-r)?

Answer (score 1):

This really sounds/looks like an XY problem. I would advise rethinking your general code & data design. For example, why is column 1 labelled `month` but then contains entries `"mazda"`, `"yamaha"`, `"car"` and `"total"`?

For what it's worth, you can reproduce your expected output with

```
rbind(df, c(month = "total", df[df$month == "mazda", -1] * df[df$month == "car", -1]))
## A tibble: 4 x 3
## Groups:   month [4]
#  month  april   may
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 mazda   11    14
#2 yamaha  12    15
#3 car      0.1   0.5
#4 total    1.1   7
```